# Variables being overwritten when using new

Tags: c++, memory, dynamic, overwrite

I'm having a problem with dynamic memory allocations in c++. I have to write a function that solves a maze stored in a .dat file. The walls are made of # separated by a space, and some points are words that need to be read in to an arbitrary length c string. This c string is then stored in the maze array. My problem is that my c strings keep overwriting previous ones in memory. How can I tell the program not to overwrite certain blocks of memory?

This is the function the initialises the maze array:

```
int LoadMaze(Maze& maze, int& width, int& height, char fname[])
{
    ifstream ifs(fname);
    int stringLength;
    char inputChar;
    char* newCString;

    if (ifs.good())
    {
        ifs >> width >> height;

        maze = new char*[width*height];

        for (int i=0;i<width*height;i++)
        {
            stringLength = 0;
            inputChar = '1';
            while(inputChar != ' ')
            {
                inputChar = ifs.get();
                if(inputChar != ' ' && inputChar != '\n')
                {
                    newCString = resizeChar(newCString, stringLength);
                    newCString[stringLength++] = inputChar;
                }
            }
            //maze = resizeMaze(maze, i);
            maze[i] = newCString;
        }
        ifs.close();
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        cerr << "File not found." << endl;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Since the C string has to be an arbitrary length, resizeChar increases the cstring size by one. Then the pointer to that cstring is stored in maze.

```
char* resizeChar(char* stringStart, int oldSize)
{
    int counter = 0;
    char* tempPtr = new char[oldSize + 1];

    for(counter = 0; counter < oldSize; counter++)
    {
        *(tempPtr + counter) = *(stringStart + counter);
    }
    delete[] stringStart;

    return (tempPtr);
}
```

Comment: Why not use std::string and avoid all this nonsense?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, I had thought that, and it would be nice, but assignment requirements. Because apparently this is the best way to learn.

Comment: Then I'm not sure what we can do to help you. We can tell you better ways to do it, but if you don't have that option, you'll have to learn how to do it this way. There's not really a coherent question in there. Find and fix the bugs.

Comment: The question is how do I stop new values of newCString from being written in the same memory location as previous ones?

Answer (score 2):

You are passing an uninitialized value to your function:

```
char* newCString;

....

newCString = resizeChar(newCString, stringLength);
```

To fix this you need to give `newCString` a sensible initial value, and make sure that `resizeChar` can handle that scenario.

It would be better to initialize `newCString` each time around the loop. That also avoids the problem that you are using the same buffer for every row of the maze.

Another major problem is that you never null-terminate the strings you are building. So once you have gone `maze[i] = newCString;`, that row is just pointing to some characters but you have lost the information of how many characters are in the string.  And if you try to output this string then you will buffer overflow and start outputting garbage.

You need to allocate 1 more byte than the number of characters in the string, and make the last one of those be `'\0'`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it didn't fix the overwrite problem. On the second iteration of the for loop, it stores newCString in the same memory location is in the first iteration. So if they're all single chars, then maze ends up being an array full of the same value

Answer (score 0):

> The question is how do I stop new values of newCString from being written in the same memory location as previous ones?

If you replace the old value of a variable with a new one, then the old value will be overwritten because a variable, during its life, does not move in memory. If you don't want to change the value, simply don't write code that changes it. Set the value of `newCString` to the value you want it to hold and do not change its value from then one.